# RxJava Subject и SocketIo

Tags: android, rxjava, kotlin, rxandroid

В проекте использую `RxJava`, и сокеты. С первой попытки не удалось самостоятельно обернуть сокеты в `Observable`, начал спрашивать, говорят чтобы я через `Subject`ы оборачивал.

В дальнейшем получилось обернуть в простые `Obsevable`

```
return Observable.create { subscriber ->
            SocketService.mSocket.emit("add user", "name", Ack {
                response ->
                subscriber.onNext(response as JSONObject)
            })
        }
```

Все отрабатывает. Про сабжекты не могу понять, нужно ли их использовать? Если все поведение которое мне нужно, это отправлять ответы из колбэка, не надо ни `ReplaySubject` ни `Behavior`. Подписчик будет один.

Смотрю [пример](https://blog.simplypatrick.com/posts/2016/2016-03-04-using-rxjava-on-android/), но мне кажется избыточным столько действий.